# In Workshop and Foundry actions form in Ontology management : Auto populate a date that is x years ahead of the input "date"

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I have create an action form with two input fields (date picker).
"created_at" and "finalized_at" and wish to know how can I modify/re-config the form in Ontology management or in Workshop, so that the "finalized_at" will automatically show the date is x years ahead the input "date"

What did you tried:
May be I can modify [following function](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/input-output-types/), but can't find more detailed information on how to do it in workshop or in Action form.

```
@Edits(Ticket)

@OntologyEditFunction()

public updateDueDate(ticket: Ticket, dueDate?: LocalDate): void {

    if (dueDate) {

        ticket.dueDate = dueDate;

    } else {

        // By default, set due date to next week

        ticket.dueDate = LocalDate.now().plusDays(7);

    }

}
```

Expected result

1. Use date picker to select a given date
2. New input field for input x years
3. Based on the selected date and input value for x years, auto output as a date that is x years ahead in finalized_to

Answer (score 0):

In Workshop, you can achieve this by configuring a **[Variable Transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK7zA.png)**. This will allow you to take the output date from the date picker and automatically create a new variable that is N days/weeks/months/years after the input date. The value of N can either be hardcoded or an output from an input field in Workshop. You can also achieve this by creating a function backed variable, though there's no need to edit the object's property. Instead you can just take in a date var as an input to the function, add seven days, and return the new date. I strongly recommend the no-code option though for maintainability.

This new modified date variable can then be passed as an input into your action form. You can configure default values for action forms in the **[Parameter Defaults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG3U7.png)** section of the action configuration in Workshop.